# $anchorScroll not working if div contains ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am using $anchorscroller and location hash for scroll down to each section.
It is working correctly. But if any div having ng-if condition, then this anchor scroll is not working.

For example,

```
<div id="Mrgr" ng-if="mgrlist.length>0">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

In angular, I am using the below code:

```
$location.hash("Mrgr");
$anchorScroll();
```

If I remove the `ng-if` then this scrolling working fine.

Any one have any solution to fix this?

Comment: Maybe mgrlist.length is not >0 and the element is removed from the DOM 
`If the expression is falsy then the element is removed from the DOM tree. If it is truthy a copy of the compiled element is added to the DOM tree.`... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Thanks. But mgrlist.length is true. But still it not working.